# return fraction when dividing with Ruby

Tags: ruby

What can I do with my method `fraction` so it returns the fraction of a division, rather than the decimal value. So:

```
fraction(a,b)
  (a/b)
end

fraction(5,3) #=> (5/3)
```

I would want it to return a value similar to how negative exponents work:

```
8**-2 #=> (1/64)
```

Comment: You want 5/3 to be returned..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a hint:

```
(8**-2).class #=> Rational
```

So this already exists in Ruby via the `Rational` class, which you can call as a method to create rational numbers.

```
Rational(5, 3)  #=> (5/3)
Rational('5/3') #=> (5/3)
Rational('0.3') #=> (3/10)
```

[Check out the documentation here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Rational.html)

Answer (score 2):

Using Ruby 2.1's new literal for rational numbers, any of the following will work:

```
5r/3 # => (5/3)
5/3r # => (5/3)
5r/3r # => (5/3)
```

Comment: Doh.  I asked about this, and didn't remember to answer with this when I read it.  Good one @sawa